# Hammer.js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I'm using Hammer.js and I've included Hammer and the Hammer JQuery plugin like this:

```
<script src='res/stat/js/hammer.js'></script>
<script src='res/stat/js/jquery.hammer.js'></script>
```

Now, with this code I'm trying to get double tap to work:

```
<script>
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName('snap_item');
    var hammertime = Hammer(element).on("doubletap", function(event) {
        alert('hello!');
    });   
</script>
```

The element with classname 'snap_item' exists and is spelled correctly. The path to Hammer.js and the JQ plugin are also correct. I've tested it on the iPhone 5S and it doesn't do anything when I double tap the element.

Does anyone know what's going wrong here? I have JQuery V2 included as well. Is that causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements. The Hammer constructor can only take one element. Initialize each on it's own:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('snap_item');

[].slice.call(elements).forEach(function(element) {
    var hammertime = new Hammer(element);
    hammertime.on('doubletap', function(event) {
         alert('hello!');
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nw6dvgck/**

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work. On JSFiddle it works, but when I copy the exact same code, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using the latest hammer.js? I didn't include jQuery hammer.

Comment: Yeah, it's the latest Hammer.js

Comment: For me works in jsfiddle. I don't understand whole example but thanks